# How to Prevent Identical input of Value in Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, kendo-ui

i need to Filter Duplicate data entry in my Kendo Grid when Saving Drop Down Value.

I have this Dropdown that shows day of the Week e.g Monday, Tuesday and so on

But i want to prevent this by showing a message that will prevent the user to save the day that is saved before unless delete it. Can someone Help me with this situation??

My Drop down List :

```
<p>
                <label for="dllAvailableDay">
                    <abbr title="This is a required field.">
                        <em><font color="red">*</font></em></abbr>
                    Available Day</label>
                <span>
                    @Html.DropDownList("dllAvailableDay", new SelectList(ViewBag.availableDayList, "ID", "Display_Value", workerAvailableDay), "[Please Select]",
          new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    {"class","validate[required] inputLong"}
                })
                </span>
            </p>
```

Controller for Viewbag:

```
 private void GetAvailableDayList()
        {
            var availableDayList = (from a in db.Lookups
                                    where a.Domain == "AVAILABLEDAY"
                                    select a).ToList();

            ViewBag.AvailableDayList = availableDayList;
        }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript you could have a list of 'days used' and push and pop a day is used and remove when no longer used. Then use that array to validate selection (Add a select event to your dropdown).